# Highlighted color keep on the table cell when I click back to the table in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c

I have a table view in my program, (1)when I click on a row, (2)it will be changed to a view, (3)If I click back button, it will go back to the table list.

My problem is when I go back to the table list and the highlighted color still keep on the row, how can I **erase the highlighted color** after clicked on the row?

Thanks

(1)

[image: (1)]

(2)

[image: (2)]

(3)

[image: (3)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in you `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

```
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
```